# put value on screen without window python mac

Tags: python, user-interface, python-imaging-library

do any of you guys know of a way that I could display a constantly changing variable on my screen kinda like the 144 below.

Everything I have tried either requires a window, doesn't work in python, or doesn't work on mac.

Any help or pointers are appreciated!

[image: similar to this 144 in the picture]

Comment: can you just create a transparent backround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to acheive this with Pygame, and making the background transparent.